# Is there something like OldStyleClass.mro()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, method-resolution-order

I am trying to understand MRO in old-style classes. It would be handy to have an equivalent for NewStyleClass.mro() (or NewStyleClass.__mro__).

Is there something like OldStyleClass.mro()?
Perhaps a quick and easy way to simulate it?

Comment: You make the old-style class a new-style class?

Comment: Old-style classes have been deprecated for a while, I'd focus purely on new-style at this point.

Comment: Let's say I use Python 2.7.x and have `class A: pass and class B(A):pass` or something much more complex. I want to know from Python itself how old style DLR works. I hope this is what you asked about.

Comment: I am not going to use old classes. I just want to know how they worked (or possibly I might be forced to, who knows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the resources of the `inspect` module with old style classes:

```
class A:  # "old" style class
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

hasattr(B, '__mro__')
# -> False

import inspect
print inspect.getmro(B)
# -> (<class __main__.B at 0x7f1b5ee1b530>, <class __main__.A at 0x7f1b5ee1b4c8>)
```

Comment: Just checked with Python 2.7, dunno with others when I'm using new style classes since years.